# Is it possible to further filter on MAX results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so

A)
[image]

As you can see, the same `ID` can have multiple `Revision ID`s

Now, I can grab all **the latest** revision for each ID by using `MAX` with `GROUP BY` like so:

```
SELECT *, MAX(revision_id)
FROM content_moderation_state_field_revision
GROUP BY id DESC;
```

B) [image]

As you can see here, the Revision ID of 47141 is the latest revision for ID 3282

**So here is my goal**

What I want to do is to further filter these (screenshot B) results down to only `published` Moderation States of the latest/highest revision.

However, if I try

```
SELECT *, MAX(revision_id)
FROM content_moderation_state_field_revision
WHERE moderation_state = 'published'
GROUP BY id DESC;
```

I get

C) [image]

Which is not what I want, because it is no longer grabbing the latest/highest revision for each ID. 47139 is not the highest/latest revision for 3282, it's 47141 as show in screenshot B.

What I want here is to only show the 3278 row because that's the only row with also has the latest/highest revision that has a published moderation state (See screenshot B)

**In a nutschell**

> I want to select only rows which are both 'published' and have the
> maximum revision_id

How can I achieve my goal? Is it possible?

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully it's more clear now :)

Comment: So, you want to select only rows which are both 'published' and have the maximum revision_id for that id?

Comment: @SimonGoater correct

Comment: There was a typo then, `END` and `)` should be exchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional logic along with a `HAVING` clause  such as

```
SELECT id, 
       MAX(revision_id) AS revision_id,
       MAX(moderation_state) AS moderation_state
  FROM content_moderation_state_field_revision
 GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN moderation_state = 'published' THEN revision_id END) = 
       MAX(revision_id);
```